# Angular: merge more than 6 observables?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I've tried to add another observable to my merge, so starting from the correct

```
return merge(   
          this.paginator.page, this.sort.sortChange, 
          this.cmdtyChanges.pipe(map(cmdties =>{
            return {'cmdties': cmdties};})), 
          this.bookChanges.pipe(map(book =>{
            return {'book': book};})), 
          this.start.pipe(map(update => {
            return {'start':update};})), 
          this.end.pipe(map(update => {
            return {'end':update};})))
```

I wanted to add other two like below

```
  return merge(   
      this.paginator.page, this.sort.sortChange, 
      this.cmdtyChanges.pipe(map(cmdties =>{
        return {'cmdties': cmdties};})), 
      this.bookChanges.pipe(map(book =>{
        return {'book': book};})), 
      this.cptyChanges.pipe(map(cpties =>{
        return {'cpties': cpties};})),
      this.traderChanges.pipe(map(traders =>{
        return {'traders': traders};})),
      this.start.pipe(map(update => {
        return {'start':update};})), 
      this.end.pipe(map(update => {
        return {'end':update};})))
```

but it doesn't compile with more than 6 of them...

How to detour it?

### Edit

Sorry for the edit, but having seen the answer, I think I must show the pipe after the merge

so I'm doing

```
.pipe(map((merged) => {
          var mustLoad = false;
          if ('book' in merged) {
            this.sendMessage(`book selected: ${merged.book}`);
            this.selBook = merged.book;
          }
          if ('traders' in merged) {
            this.sendMessage(`traders selected: ${merged.traders.length}`);
            this.selTraders = merged.traders;
            console.log('current traders', this.selTraders);
          }
```

and it looks like when I pass a union of more than 6 different types `Observable<...> | Observable<...> | ...` the type of `merged` in `.pipe(map((merged) => {` becomes unknown and the code after that does not compile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comment, I've seen that the use of a spread operator makes the result always unknown while I can have it properly typed if I stay under 6 different observables. Notice also that this issue is not fully reproducible on stackblitz since the signature of `merge` is not compliant there.

Therefore I implement an internal merge for cases reducible to the

```
interface MyChange {
  myvalue: string[], mytype: 'traders'|'cpties'|'cmdties'
}
```

and - avoiding type assertions as much as possible to keep type safety - I manage the whole wrapped merge as

```
  return merge(
    this.paginator.page,
    this.sort.sortChange,
    this.bookChanges.pipe(map(book => {
      return { 'book': book };
    })),

    (merge(this.cmdtyChanges.pipe(map(cmdties => {
      const ret : MyChange = { 'myvalue': cmdties, 'mytype': 'cmdties' };
      return ret;
    })),
      this.cptyChanges.pipe(map(cpties => {
      const ret : MyChange =  { 'mytype': 'cpties', 'myvalue': cpties };
      return ret;
      })),
      this.traderChanges.pipe(map(traders => {
      const ret : MyChange =  { 'mtyype': 'traders', 'myvalue': traders };
      return ret;
      })))   ),

    this.start.pipe(map(update => {
      return { 'start': update };
    })),
    this.end.pipe(map(update => {
      return { 'end': update };
    }))
  )
```

in such a way that I can finally pipe the safely typed - not unknown - result into

```
    .pipe(map((merged ) => {
      var mustLoad = false;
      if ('book' in merged) {
        this.sendMessage(`book selected: ${merged.book}`);
        this.selBook = merged.book;
      }
      if ('mytype' in merged && merged.mytype == 'traders') {
        this.sendMessage(`traders selected: ${merged.myvalue.length}`);
        this.selTraders = merged.myvalue;
        console.log('current traders', this.selTraders);
      }
```

and so on...

Answer (score 3):

RxJS has typings prepared only for a limited number of combinations. So if you have more than 6 source Observables you can first make an array of Observables and then use spread operator (`...`) to pass them into `merge()`:

```
const sources = [
  this.paginator.page,
  this.sort.sortChange,
  // other-sources,
];

merge(...sources).subscribe();
```

Demo with 7 source Observables: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-luldtu?devtoolsheight=60

Comment: But I think it is not going to work: I guess the problem is that ultimately it does not recognize the type of the result of the merge... It does not compile for errors due to the fact that the merged type is unknown

Comment: That should work as well or you can use your own type with `merge<A | B | C | D | E | F | more>()` I guess. `merge()` should create a union of all types.

Comment: maybe I'm too ignorant about typescript I'm saying that  `merge<A | B | C | D | E |F | G>` (union of 7 different types) does not compile (or it results in unknown type) while merge<A | B | C | D | E |F > (union of 6 different types) does. Let me edit my question to show the pipe after the merge

Comment: I tried this and it needs to be a little different. `merge()` always returns `unknown` so you'll need to type this yourself, see this https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-luldtu?devtoolsheight=60

Comment: Ok, I'm going to use an `interface MyChange { myvalue: string, mytype: string }` . If you could please update your answer to reflect this so that I can accept it. What you've written now does not have any effect. Notice furthermore that the type of `merged` becomes `unknown` **only** with **more than 6** different observables. Thank you in advance

Comment: I'm editing my code. I see that merge is always unknow if you use the spread operator like in your answer, but in my original question without the spread operator it is not unknown with less than 6 observables. I'm going to use an internal merge with interface `MyChange { myvalue: string[], mytype: string }` and I will avoid the spread operator.